# How to hide fields when adding a something to a custom list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a custom list, created a view for it. One view for normal users another for admins. When you go to add something new to the list the fields I want to hide from normal users are there. Is there a setting somewhere to fix or change this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to the controller behind the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.isAdmin = isAdmin();
    return View();  
}


private Boolean isAdmin()
{
    if (User.IsInRole("admin"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and then in the View, wrap the context you need with:

```
 @{
     if (ViewBag.isAdmin)
     {                                          
     //....only admins can see me!
     }

 }
```